# Support of sum of Dirac measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, dirac-delta

Let $\mu$ be the measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Find $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)$, where $\mu=\sum_{k\geq 1}a_k\delta_{x_k}$ and $(x_k)_{k\geq 1}$ is an arbitrary sequence of real numbers.

Since $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)$ is the collection of closed sets whose complement has measure zero, wouldn't we have that $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)=\{x_k\}$ for $k\geq 1$?

This question seems too trivial to me, but I am afraid I might be missing something.

I'd appreciate if anyone can point out where I am wrong or if I am correct.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\mu$? is it $\sum_{k \ge 1} a_k \delta_k$?

Comment: The question as written is a bit difficult to answer. Do you by any chance also impose the condition that $x_k \neq x_j$ for $k\neq j$? Otherwise that series might not be well-defined. Under the condition above there is a nice characterization of the support. It is instructive to look at the case $\sum_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} \delta_q$. What is the support? The what is the support of $\sum_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}$? After that you should understand what you want to prove in the general case.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it $\mu$ is the sum of $\delta$'s. @Severin Schraven, the problem does not have that restriction but if it is a reasonable assumption, then I'll make it. $\sum_{q\in \mathbb{Q}}\delta_q $ , wouldn't that support be rationals? and for $\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} \delta_q$, wouldn't that be the rationals between 0 and 1? I guess I have not seen what you are trying to show me.

Comment: That's not a linear combination, as that would be a finite sum.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the title of the question.

Comment: @Schach21 As noted in the accepted answer below, the support is closed. Probably my hint was not as instructive as I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_k \geq 0$ for all $k$ then the support is exactly the closure $E$ of $\{x_k: a_k >0\}$.  Proof: By ignoring the zero terms this proof reduces to the case where $a_k >0$ for all $k$. Since $\mu \{x_k\} >0$ for each $k$ it follows that each $x_k$ is in the support. Since the support is closed (by definition ) it follows that $E$ is contained in the support. On the other hand $\mu(E^{c})=0$ (since each term in the sum is $0$) so the support is also contained in $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose all $a_k >0$ and the $x_k$ enumerate the rationals. Then supp$(\mu)=\mathbb R.$ That's because there is no nonempty subset $U$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $\mu(U)=0.$